# Cannot Retrieve WebAPI Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular

In Visual Studio I have two applications.  One is a Angular 2 website and the other is a WebApi project.  I have a breakpoint in the WebAPI method that gets hit when the Angular service tries to retrieve data but nothing is ever displayed on the page.  Opening the browser console I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:58949/api/people. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:62761' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?  I've gotten this working by creating an MVC application that hosts both the WebAPI and the angular app but I didn't like this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to enable CORS on web api side.

I am assuming you are using WebApi Core. To enabled CORS on web api side, you will have to do these steps-

First, add dependency in project.json - "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",

then enable CORS in startup.cs like this-

```
app.UseCors(builder => {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

You can find more information about CORS here - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there any security concerns to doing this?

Comment: If you want to restrict to a specific origin then you can do like this- `   app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")); `

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you face is that browser does not allow cross-origin request by default. As you say you have two websites, that have different urls, most likely just different ports on localhost in you case, but this still counts as "different" origin and is a security measure. You can always allow your web api to be accessible either by all sources or your Angular origin:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, DELETE
```

ASP.NET has a built in package that can do that for you so that you don't need boilerplate. You can read more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Basically it will just add some headers to your web api responses as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my WepApi projects.  It goes in WebApiConfig.cs.

```
        // Use NuGet to add this: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
        config.EnableCors();
```